# How to prototype on object instance that is not Object or Function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype, defineproperty

Extending Object class is not recommended, so I try to extend an object, for example:

```
var obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3};
```

Here the [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`
is same as `new Object({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})`.

I tried `obj.prototype = {d: 4}` but it set 'prototype' as property, not a real [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).
Forget [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)!
Also tried [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create): Why does this not work? ...

```
var ext = Object.create(obj, {'d': { value:4 }});
console.log(obj.isPrototypeOf(ext)) // => true! obj is prototype of ext
console.log(ext); // => {d: 4}
console.log(obj); // => {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Console.log say `obj.isPrototypeOf(ext) == true` so why is `ext` not `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}` ?

*How to prototype on object instance that is not Object class or Function?*

**Update**: As *Nicholas Tower* answer i have missed enumerable in [the second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Parameters) that should be: `{'d': { value:4, enumerable: true }}`

I had issue with arrow-dropdown in Chrome console that I missed to click to see the inherited values. I could have used `assign()` to "extend" *obj*. Now it show `obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Prototype_mutation) `{d: 4}` that is ok. From OO view that means `obj` [extends](http://www-lia.deis.unibo.it/materiale/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends.html) `{d: 4}`*. Made a prototype on the object obj.

I accepted answer from *t.888* that helped me see how `console.log` show objects and the correct way to extend an existing object.

Comment: Wow, re-read the very first link you provided. Specifically the sub heading: _**Enhanced Object literals**_. Quote: "_**In ES2015, object literals are extended to support setting the prototype at construction**_" with the next example showing exactly how to accomplish that with `__proto__`.

Comment: Yes - Long live `__proto__`. Nice syntactic sugar for shothands, functions and computed keys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) to set a prototype but its considered a legacy feature:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, __proto__: { c: 3 }}
console.log(obj.c) // 3
```

A better way is to extend an existing object with `Object.create`. It's convenient to define a function
for this purpose:

```
/**
 * Extend an object by creating a new object with the given prototype.
 */
function extend(proto, obj) {
  // Create a new object with the given prototype
  const sub = Object.create(proto)

  if (obj) {
    // Copy the properties from 'obj' to the new object.
    Object.assign(sub, obj)
  }

  // Return the new object.
  return sub
}
```

```
// Define an object to serve as a prototype.
const proto = { a: 1, b: 2 }

// Create a new object with the given prototype.
const extended = extend(proto, { c: 3 })

console.log(extended.a, extended.b, extended.c) // 1 2 3
```

However as another answer pointed out, it won't show the prototype properties actually
*on* the object:

```
console.log(extended) // { c: 3 }
```

It's there though, it's just not on the object itself but on its prototype:

```
for (let key in extended) {
  console.log(key, extended[key])
}
```

Output:

```
c 3
a 1
b 2
```

```
console.log(extended.__proto__) // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

**`Object.assign`**

If you just want to copy and/or combine objects, use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const first = {a: 1}
const second = {b: 2}

// Put the properties from 'second' onto 'first'.
Object.assign(first, second) // first: {a: 1, b: 2}

// Copy 'first' and 'second' to a new object.
const third = Object.assign({c: 3}, first, second) // third: {c: 3, a: 1, b: 2}
```

This is roughly equivalent to copying properties manually:

```
const first = {a: 1}
const second = {b: 2}

for (let key in second) {
  if (second.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    first[key] = second[key]
  }
}

console.log(first) // {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Generalizing that code, we can create an approximation of `Object.assign` that works
on [older browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=assign) where `Object.assign` may not present:

```
/**
 * Assign properties from object arguments [1..n] to the
 * zeroth object argument.
 */
function assign() {
  var first, rest

  // Check of Object.assign exists and use a fallback if it doesn't.
  if (typeof Object.assign === 'function') {
    // Copy each object's properties to the first one.
    return Object.assign.apply(null, arguments)
  } else {
    first = arguments[0]
    rest = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
    // Copy each object's properties to the first one.
    rest.forEach((obj) => {
      for (var key in obj) {
        // Don't copy any of obj's prototype's properties.
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          first[key] = obj[key]
        }
      }
    })
    return first
  }
}
```

```
const obj = assign({c: 3}, {a: 1}, {b: 2})
console.log(obj) // {c: 3, a: 1, b: 2}
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy with Object​.assign()?

Comment: You point out my problem here: "However as another answer pointed out, it won't show the prototype properties actually on the object".

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho, Yes I've added an example at the end of my answer.

Comment: That code could have an Object.assign-check and change the text abowe as: "Generalizing that code, we can make an optimal cross-browser assign". If Object.assign exists it use it instead of loop.

Comment: I accepted your answer as Object.create() is the correct way to extend objects. Also appointing how console.log (not) show objects included prototype. Nice extend function extending proto to sub+obj.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho, thanks! I implemented your suggestion to make `assign` work on older browsers.

Comment: WORKS! Just replaced Object.create(obj, {'d': { value:4 }}) by extend(obj, {'d': 4}). Gives exactly same result in console. To see prototype-chain we have to click.

Answer (score 2):

> why is ext not {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4} ?

It is, but you didn't make that `d` enumerable, so console.log doesn't see it.

```js
const obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3};
const ext = Object.create(obj, {'d': { 
  value:4, 
  enumerable: true // <---- added this
}});
console.log('ext', ext);
for (const key in ext) {
  if (ext.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log('own property', key, ext[key]);
  } else {
    console.log('inherited property', key, ext[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if enumerable the console.log will not write  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}. It write a drop-down arrow in front of {d:4}. I missed to click to unfold the structure. The enumeration works only on iteration.

Comment: Yes, console.log behaves differently in different browsers.

Comment: It is not {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4} and should not be. It is {'d': 4} with prototype to the rest. Now I understand why and hope you too.

Comment: `It is not {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}` i certainly agree that the chrome and firefox developer tools display it with the inherited properties in an expandable section. Did you run the stack overflow snippet? i see the full log there. `and should not be` I'm not sure why you say that. The specification for console.log leaves it up to the implementation how it wants to represent the data. https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger references https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer, which says "The printer operation is implementation-defined."

Comment: I tested in console of both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: `I tested in console of both Chrome and Firefox`. Yes, i understand that. Chrome and firefox are conforming to the spec for console.log. But so too are other javascript engines which format it differently. The stack overflow snippet is as an example of a console.log which lists all the properties, inherited or otherwise: https://imgur.com/8eHJGlB

Comment: Oh sorry :( I didn't click Run code snippet. Now I see it say {
  "d": 4,
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}